# Uncaught Exception: User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back

Tags: magento2

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back in /var/www/html/vype/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 3981 in /var/www/html/vype/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61\nStack trace:\n#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(256, 'Some transactio...', '/var/www/html/v...', 3981, Array)\n#1 /var/www/html/vype/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(3981): trigger_error('Some transactio...', 256)\n#2 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->__destruct()\n#3 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/vype/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php on line 61, referer:

Comment: I'm getting above error while placing orders for unknown reason. and this is not frequent issue. Customers are not able to place the order some times they are getting timeout issue.  Could anyone please help me

Comment: did you get any solution?

Comment: No I didnt get any solutions